# How to delete multiple rows in SQL where id = (x to y)

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I am trying to run a SQL query to delete rows with id's 163 to 265 in a table

I tried this to delete less number of rows

```
    DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id IN (264, 265)
```

But when it comes to delete 100's of rows at a time, Is there any query similar to above method
I am also trying to use this kind of query but failed to execute it

```
    DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = )
```

Please tell me the query to do the above action...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Delete Records within a specific Range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225036/sql-delete-records-within-a-specific-range)

Comment: This is not a duplicated from the above mentioned...the other relates to deletion in range of consecutives, the question in this refers to deletion of possible non-consecutive id's, a list of ids..

Answer (score 252):

If you need to delete based on a list, you can use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE id IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

If you need to delete based on the result of a query, you can also use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE id IN (select aColumn from ...);
```

(Notice that the subquery must return only one column)

If you need to delete based on a range of values, either you use `BETWEEN` or you use inequalities:

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE id BETWEEN bottom_value AND top_value;
```

or

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE id >= a_value AND id <= another_value;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have used BETWEEN and Its executed successfully to my requirement.

Comment: @baluzapps If you find this answer useful, accept it ;)

Comment: A question related to this:
What if I have composite key?

Comment: @MayurBeldar: if you have a new question, post it *as a question*, not as a comment

Answer (score 34):

You can use `BETWEEN`:

```
DELETE FROM table
where id between 163 and 265
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try this:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id >=163 and id<= 265
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY DESC
```

Get the range that you want to delete Ex: 3 to 10

```
 DELETE FROM your_table
 WHERE id BETWEEN 3 AND 10;
```

Make sure to add min value fist in BETWEEN Clause

Answer (score -7):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_DELETE_MULTI_ROW]       
@CODE XML
,@ERRFLAG  CHAR(1) = '0' OUTPUT    

AS        

SET NOCOUNT ON  
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED  

DELETE tb_SampleTest
    WHERE 
        CODE IN(
            SELECT Item.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)')
            FROM  @CODE.nodes('RecordList/ID') AS x(Item)
            )

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    SET @ERRFLAG = 200

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Get string value delete

```
<RecordList>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ID>2</ID>
</RecordList>
```